# Reference a file when the date in file name is changing daily

Tags: excel, vba

All cell locations remain the same, the only thing that is changing is the date in the file name.

I am cutting and pasting from one Excel workbook to another.

How can I perform the required function when the file name is changed every day?

```vb
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=108
Windows("Standard 15OCT23.csv").Activate
Range("A2:H17").Select
Selection.Cut
Windows("Generic 15OCT23.csv").Activate
Rows("122:122").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=141
```

UPDATE

I came into work today and tried to run this on the report that was pulled for today and it would not work.
After some major editing to the code. I have a VBA code that should work, but it just does not want to cooperate.

```vb
Sub StandardToGenericDataXfer()
    Dim sDate As String
    sDate = UCase(format(Date, "ddMMMyy")) ' Format the current date

    Dim standardWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim genericWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook

    ' Loop through open workbooks
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        Dim wbName As String
        wbName = UCase(wb.Name)
        If (InStr(wbName, "STANDARD") > 0 Or InStr(wbName, "GENERIC") > 0) And _
           InStr(wbName, sDate) > 0 And InStr(wbName, ".CSV") > 0 Then
            If InStr(wbName, "STANDARD") > 0 Then
                Set standardWorkbook = wb
            ElseIf InStr(wbName, "GENERIC") > 0 Then
                Set genericWorkbook = wb
            End If
        End If
    Next wb

    ' Check if both workbooks were found
    If Not (standardWorkbook Is Nothing) And Not (genericWorkbook Is Nothing) Then
        ' Copy data from standardWorkbook to genericWorkbook
        standardWorkbook.Sheets(standardWorkbook.Name).Range("A2:H16").Copy
        genericWorkbook.Sheets(genericWorkbook.Name).Range("A122").Insert Shift:=xlDown
' More Copy/Insert commands here
MsgBox "Data transfer complete.", vbInformation
    Else
        Dim message As String
        message = "One or both workbooks not found:" & vbCrLf
        If Not standardWorkbookFound Then message = message & "Standard workbook not found." & vbCrLf
        If Not genericWorkbookFound Then message = message & "Generic workbook not found."
        MsgBox message, vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue I am not running into is that even though I have both files open, example "Generic 15OCT23" and "Standard 15OCT23" my VBA code is now not able to find the open files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The `Date` function provides the current system date.
- The `Format` function converts the date into a string using the desired date format.
- The resulting date string is then concatenated with a file name.

```
    Dim sDate As String
    sDate = UCase(Format(Date, "ddMMMyy"))
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=108
    Windows("Standard " & sDate & ".csv").Activate
    Range("A2:H17").Cut
    Windows("Generic " & sDate & ".csv").Activate
    Rows("122:122").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=141
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Date function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Format function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

By the way, the post is definitely worth reading.

> [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

---

The code could be simplified as below.
btw, `Cut` w/o `Paste` does not make any change.

```
Dim sDate As String
sDate = UCase(Format(Date, "ddMMMyy"))
Workbooks("Standard " & sDate & ".csv").Range("A2:H17").Cut
Workbooks("Generic " & sDate & ".csv").Rows(122).Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Comment: To increment a date through the month `sDateString = " 2023-01-11T"` this is the form of the date I am using. `sDateString = " " & Format(DateAdd("d", i, "01-Sep-2023"), "yyyy-mm-dd") & "T"` where `i` increments in a loop from 1 to 31. To generate yesterdays date for example use `i = -1`

Comment: @Danielson This is not how StackOverflow works. You asked a question and you got an answer. **If you have an other question, post it as a new question.** To improve your own efficiency, try to learn from the answers you have got (and look at similar questions/answers for guidance)

Comment: @Danielson The logic is same.  `Sheets("Generic " & sDate).Select              
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Generic " & sDate & "'!R[13]C[4]"`

Answer (score 2):

### Identify Open Workbooks

- If you can ensure that only the 'matching' workbooks (the ones with the same date) are open, you could use the following:

```vb
Sub CutInsertRange()

    Dim wb As Workbook, swb As Workbook, dwb As Workbook

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        If LCase(wb.Name) Like "standard *.csv" Then
            Set swb = wb
        ElseIf LCase(wb.Name) Like "generic *.csv" Then
            Set dwb = wb
        End If
    Next wb
    
    If swb Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Standard workbook not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If dwb Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Generic workbook not found!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    swb.Sheets(1).Range("A2:H17").Cut
    dwb.Sheets(1).Rows("122").Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown

End Sub
```