# Copy Data between Excel Workbooks with MACRO

Tags: excel, vba

After getting some assistance yesterday, I came into work today and tried to run this on the report that was pulled for today and it would not work. After some editing, I have a VBA code that should work, but it just does not want to cooperate.

```
Sub StandardToGenericDataXfer()
    ' Clear and delete rows in the standard and generic sheets
    ' Replace "ddMMMyy" with the actual date format in your sheet names
    Dim sDate As String
    sDate = format(Date, "ddMMMyy")

    ' Declare and assign the standard and generic sheets based on the date
    Dim standardSheet As Worksheet
    Dim genericSheet As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next
    Set standardSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Standard " & sDate)
    Set genericSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Generic " & sDate)
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Check if the sheets were found
    If standardSheet Is Nothing Or genericSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "One or both sheets not found:" & vbCrLf & _
               IIf(standardSheet Is Nothing, "Standard sheet not found." & vbCrLf, "") & _
               IIf(genericSheet Is Nothing, "Generic sheet not found.", ""), vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Copy data from standardSheet to genericSheet
            standardSheet.Range("A2:H16").Copy
            genericSheet.Range("A122").Insert Shift:=xlDown
' More Copy/Insert commands here
MsgBox "Data transfer complete.", vbInformation
    Else
        Dim message As String
        message = "One or both workbooks not found:" & vbCrLf
        If Not standardWorkbookFound Then message = message & "Standard workbook not found." & vbCrLf
        If Not genericWorkbookFound Then message = message & "Generic workbook not found."
        MsgBox message, vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue I am not running into is that even though I have both files open, example "Generic 15OCT23" and "Standard 15OCT23" my VBA code is now not able to find the open Standard and Generic files.
All cells between reports are the same, so the only thing that is changing is the date in the workbook and sheet.

Comment: What is `standardSheet` and `genericSheet`? Are those variables? You don't assign anything to them.

Comment: Nor are they declared. Make sure you're using `Option Explicit` to avoid/easily fix these type of errors. (unless you've change the codename of these sheets which I still don't understand why you would). standard/genericWorkbookFound is not declared nor assigned anything either.

Comment: There appears to be some code missing ie The first `If` part of the `Else` block.

Comment: Your question is about files, but the code now refers to worksheets within the currently open workbook (after your edit). Which one is it?

Comment: I will have two workbooks open. Since the cell locations between the two documents are fixed, I simply want to move the required data from the standard to generic with the click of a MACRO.  There is only one sheet in the workbook and that matches the workbook's name in each.  I am most likely overthinking this.

Comment: Not sure if you're overthinking things, however, if you're having two workbooks open, your code prior to your edit was fine for the workbook variables. Once you set your workbook to either, you can also set your worksheet variable to the correct one. For example: `Set generalSheet = generalWorkbook(generalWorkbook.Name)` (if it is exactly the same). `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook the code is in which will be incorrect for both your sheets, I suppose.

Comment: To reference the one and only sheet in an open `csv` file, you could e.g. use `Set standardSheet = Workbooks("Standard " & sDate & ".csv").Sheets(1)`. `ThisWorkbook` means the workbook containing this code. Have you looked at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77295638) to your previous question? It kind of makes it clear (`swb.Sheets(1)` or `standardWorkbook.Sheets(1)`).